# MySQL - how can I write to a file from the shell?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write to a file with this query from the shell command lin:

```
mysql --user=my_user --password='my_password' -e "select concat_ws ('\t' , user_id , first_name , last_name , user_email ) from users" into outfile '/hiking_contacts.txt';
```

Which I was hoping would create a text file, but it is not really working. Would anyone know where I went wrong here?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Does the MySQL server user have write permissions to the root directory `/`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes that user has write permissions

Comment: I don't mean the logged in user `mysql_user`, I mean the _system_ user the MySQL server daemon runs as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql --user=my_user --password='my_password' -e "select concat_ws ('\t' , user_id , first_name , last_name , user_email ) from users;" >> hiking_contacts.txt
```

And check the permissions.

Have a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/command-line-options.html

Comment: that gave an error no database selected..not sure why..looking into it

Comment: Oh yeah duh me, the db name is not specified :) How do I add the db name in that query?  Thank you!

Comment: You'll need `--batch` or you'll end up with a table surrounding this.

Comment: to select your db write it just before your table. `select * from dbName.users;`